# Merging text of files into one text file

Tags: python

I have two main files into which i want to copy few files and sort. I have written below code and it is able to merge files into Universe.tls and HighVolumeOnly.tls.

Question:

A) Is it possible to write a loop for lines 31-41

```
    with open("C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Universe.tls", 'w') as newfile:
  for f in UniverseFiles:
      with open(f) as infile:
        contents = infile.read()
        newfile.write(contents)
        
with open("C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HighVolumeOnly.tls", 'w') as newfile:
  for f in HVEFiles:
      with open(f) as infile:
        contents = infile.read()
        newfile.write(contents)
```

B) Also i want to sort Universe.tls and HighVolumeOnly.tls using a loop, lines 43-50 is not working

```
Sorting files
for files in MergeFiles:
    with open(files) as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
        lines.sort()
    with open(files) as f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line)
```

Code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Thu Oct  5 19:00:33 2023

@author: eruku
"""
# Mapping directly to watchlist folder in AmiBroker
UniverseFiles = [
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HVE.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HV1Y.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HVIPO.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Gappers.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/RSNewHigh.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/RS21DMACrossover.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Launchpad.tls'          
            ]

# File list of high volume edges and gappers
HVEFiles = [
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HVE.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HV1Y.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HVIPO.tls',
            'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Gappers.tls',
            ]

MergeFiles = [
                'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Universe.tls',
                'C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HighVolumeOnly.tls'
             ]
# Line 31 starts below
with open("C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Universe.tls", 'w') as newfile:
  for f in UniverseFiles:
      with open(f) as infile:
        contents = infile.read()
        newfile.write(contents)
        
with open("C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/HighVolumeOnly.tls", 'w') as newfile:
  for f in HVEFiles:
      with open(f) as infile:
        contents = infile.read()
        newfile.write(contents)
# Line 41 ends above
# Sorting files
# for files in MergeFiles:
#     with open(files) as f:
#         lines = f.readlines()
#         lines.sort()
#     with open(files) as f:
#         for line in lines:
#             f.write(line)
     

        
# with open('C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Universe.tls', 'r') as f:
#     lines = f.readlines()
#     lines.sort()

# with open('C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists/Universe.tls', 'w') as f:
#     for line in lines:
#         f.write(line)
```

Comment: Please either include line numbers in the posted code or identify what lines you mean some other way.

Comment: If your code works, but you wish to improve it, you should probably be asking on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read all lines from each group of files into a list, sort that list then write the output file. Something like this:

```
from pathlib import Path

BASE = Path("C:/Program Files/AmiBroker/Databases/Yahoo/WatchLists")

UniverseFiles = [
    "HVE.tls",
    "HV1Y.tls",
    "HVIPO.tls",
    "Gappers.tls",
    "RSNewHigh.tls",
    "RS21DMACrossover.tls",
    "Launchpad.tls",
]

HVEFiles = [
    "HVE.tls",
    "HV1Y.tls",
    "HVIPO.tls",
    "Gappers.tls",
]


def merge_and_sort(infiles, outfile):
    lines = []
    for file in infiles:
        with open(BASE / file) as data:
            lines.extend(data.readlines())
    with open(BASE / outfile, "w") as data:
        data.writelines(sorted(lines))


def main():
    merge_and_sort(UniverseFiles, "Universe.tls")
    merge_and_sort(HVEFiles, "HighVolumeOnly.tls")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: One might even replace that first for loop with a list comprehension. Something like: `line = [line for file in infiles for data in (open(BASE / file),) for line in data.readlines()]`

Comment: @Chris There's almost certainly no benefit in doing that except for the purpose of obfuscation

Comment: Seeing TypeError: write() argument must be str, not list at data.writelines(sorted(lines)). Tried both data.writelines(sorted(",".join(lines)) and data.writelines(sorted(str(lines)) to get around but Receiving Syntax Error @ def main():.

Comment: @erukumk Apologies. Code edited. Should have extended the list rather than appended